# How ro run a shell script on aws elastic beanstalk environment instance launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, user-data, launch-configuration

I am using Terraform script to create aws elastic beanstalk environment, I need to launch a shell script on instance launch

I have already tried the following

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "Environment" {
    name = "${var.ebs_env_name}"
    application = "${var.ebs_app_name}"
    ---
    ---
    ---
    setting = {
      namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
      name = "user_data"
      value = "${file("user-data.sh")}"
   }
}
```

This is throwing error

> Error applying plan:
>
> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.Environment: ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'user_data'): Unknown configuration setting.
>           status code: 400, request id: xxxxx-xxxxxx

Please Help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the Answer, I found a solution

I have created a folder .ebextensions and created a file inside the folder called 99delayed_job.config (you can give any name)

[image]

```
commands: 
  create_post_dir: 
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre"
    ignoreErrors: true
files: 
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/99_restart_delayed_job.sh: 
    group: root
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    content: |-
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        <My shell script here>
```

A and zipped with 'Dockerrun.aws.json' this zip I am sending to s3 and used to deploy

[image]

Working fine :)

Comment: What if you want to run a long living task without blocking the deployment. In my case after trying you suggestion the eb deployer is stack in this step and never change the node status to green

Comment: !! WARNING !! "Custom platform hooks are a legacy feature that exists on Amazon Linux AMI platforms. On Amazon Linux 2 platforms, custom platform hooks in the /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/ folder are entirely discontinued. Elastic Beanstalk doesn't read or execute them. Amazon Linux 2 platforms support a new kind of platform hooks, specifically designed to extend Elastic Beanstalk managed platforms." - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any information on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk service exposing a means to modify the `user_data` on the instances. You can however adjust the AMI used, so you could use a tool like [Packer](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html) to build yourself a custom AMI that includes the `user_data` in it.